# Is there any skew function available

Tags: modeling

With the default cube how can i skew. In the coreldraw with the rectangle we can skew like this or any addon available.

[image]

Is it possible how can i do with the default cube. Any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your cube and change to Edit mode by pressing the Tab key. Select the top vertex that make up the top face, or in Face Select mode select the top face. 
[image: cube top]
With the ctrl key pressed, simply move the face/vertex selection in the desired direction.
[image: face moved]

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to [**Shear**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html?highlight=shear)

[image]

You can control the axis if you press x or y

[image]

From the manual:

> Shearing is a form of movement where parallel surfaces move past one another. During this transform, movement of the selected elements will occur along the horizontal axis of the current view. The axis location will be defined by the Pivot Point. Everything that is “above” this axis will move (Shear) in the same direction as your mouse pointer (but always parallel to the horizontal axis). Everything that is “below” the horizontal axis will move in the opposite direction.