# "leaning" a mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this... I have a basic mesh setup:

[image]

and would like to 'lean' this entire mesh so that the bottom faces remain intact, but everything else pitches, like so:

[image]

I figure I could instead build this from a flat plane that's been angled, then do my extrusions, just wanted to see if there was any way to do this after the fact.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use the **Shear** function. (Shift+Ctrl+Alt+S) See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/97433/1853

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to [**Shear**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html?highlight=shear)

[image]

You can control the axis if you press x or y

[image]

From the manual:

> Shearing is a form of movement where parallel surfaces move past one another. During this transform, movement of the selected elements will occur along the horizontal axis of the current view. The axis location will be defined by the Pivot Point. Everything that is “above” this axis will move (Shear) in the same direction as your mouse pointer (but always parallel to the horizontal axis). Everything that is “below” the horizontal axis will move in the opposite direction.